# Remove start and end border ionic-list tag in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Just want to remove the start and end border. I'm very new this programming language. I'm using below code for displaying list.

```
<ion-content>
<ion-list class="item">
  <ion-item href="#">
    Hello!
  </ion-item>
   <ion-item  href="#">
    Hello2
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>  
      </ion-content>
```

I need to remove highlighted red color circle borderlines on below mentioned screen shots. How to do?
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way would be to add *no-lines* in the `ion-list` element like this:

```
<ion-list no-lines>...</ion-list>
```

but that will remove the lines of the items too. So in order to remove only that line in the bottom you can add this style rule:

```
.md ion-list > .item:last-child, 
.md ion-list > .item-wrapper:last-child .item,
.wp ion-list > .item:last-child, 
.wp ion-list > .item-wrapper:last-child .item,
.ios ion-list > .item:last-child, 
.ios ion-list > .item-wrapper:last-child .item {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The solution that worked for me was

```
.list-ios>.item-block:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
.list-ios>.item-block:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, below is the android version

```
.list-md>.item-block:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
.list-md>.item-block:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: If you want to remove top border of ion-list in iOS, then answer of Ifeanyi Chukwu is correct.

Comment: For android devices you need replace '.list-ios' for '.list-md'

Answer (score 0):

@Ifeanyi Chukwu answer does it all.

> The solution that worked for me was

```
.list-ios>.item-block:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
.list-ios>.item-block:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, below is the android version

```
.list-md>.item-block:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
.list-md>.item-block:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide border of lasted ion-item in list.
Use this in Scss file.

```
ion-item:last-child {
   --border-style: none;
}
```